# “Eigenfunctions” of Schrödinger operators, which aren't square-integrable

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a [Schrödinger operator](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/schrodinger-operator) on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, that is a self-adjoint operator, such that
$$
  (Hf)(x) = -f''(x) + V(x) \, f(x)
  \qquad
  \text{for } f \in \mathrm D(H)
  \: .
$$
These operators play a huge role in Quantum Mechanics – especially their spectrum, which represents the [possible energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-independent_equation) a system can have. To find the pure point spectrum (ie. eigenvalues), one simply needs to solve the equation
$$
  Hf = \epsilon f,
  \qquad
  \text{where}
  \quad f \in \mathrm D(H),
  \quad \epsilon \in \mathbb R
  \: ,
  \tag{TISE}
  \label{TISE}
$$
in physics called the *Time-independent Schrödinger Equation*. However, to find the continuous spectrum, one has to use more advanced techniques from Functional Analysis. That being said, physicists quite frequently “find” the spectrum by solving \eqref{TISE}, but taking $f$ which **are not square integrable**. For example the TISE of a free Hamiltonian ($V=0$) is:
$$
  -f'' - \epsilon f = 0
  \qquad \implies \qquad
  f(x) = A \, e^{-\mathrm i \, \sqrt{\epsilon} \, x} + B \, e^{+\mathrm i \, \sqrt{\epsilon} \, x}
  \quad \text{for} \quad
  \epsilon \in [0, \infty)
  \: .
$$
Peculiarly, the spectrum of the free Hamiltonian really is $[0, \infty)$. A similar things happens in the derivation of [Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem), when $f$ is taken to be a periodic function (up to a phase) – such a wavefunction is definitely not square-integrable, but it leads to a correct prediction of the spectrum of $H$.

This doesn't seem to be just a coincidence. Is there a (mathematically rigorous) theorem, which would guarantee that the solutions of \eqref{TISE} determine the spectrum of $H$, even though they are not in the domain of $H$? When I ask the physicists, they usually respond “[something something] [Rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space).” but I couldn't find any general result which would justify this approach.

Comment: To be clear: I am not asking how to properly find the spectrum of the free Hamiltonian, neither how to rigorously derive the Bloch's theorem. What I'm interested in is the justification of the physicists' approach.

Comment: Instead of a Gelfand triple, you'd probably hew closer to the physicist's intuition by taking a nonstandard approach and defining operators as hyperreal-valued functions.  The Gelfand triple itself isn't very far from this, though.

Comment: The key idea here is that the "eigenfunctions" aren't themselves square-integrable functions, but they can *act on* square-integrable functions through the inner product.  All that remains is to embed the square-integrable functions into the larger operator space in some rigorous way (this is your "rigged hilbert space").

Comment: @user3716267 Sorry, could you elaborate? I don't follow you at all. How would hyperreals help? Is there a hyperreal extension of the Lebesgue measure which would allow periodic functions to be considered square-integrable?

Comment: Your second commend makes more sense to me – “functions that act on square-integrable functions” are multiplication operators $T_f$. One could rewrite TISE as an operator equation $$H \, T_f = \epsilon T_f + T_f \Delta$$ That sounds like an interesting approach indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Any valid Hamiltonian is self-adjoint and has a basis of eigenfunctions, which may include discrete and continuous spectral components. You can expand functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the eigenfunctions associated with some other Hamiltonian because the basis will be complete. It comes down to choosing a convenient set of eigenfunctions for the expansion. The reference coordinates are spectral coordinates for some canonical problem; the eigenfunctions for the canonical problem are sufficient to expand anything else, but the problem should be reduced by choosing a canonical type of problem and its associated eigenfunctions.

Comment: _“Any valid Hamiltonian is self-adjoint and has a basis of eigenfunctions.”_ This appears to be stretching the definition of a _basis_ quite a lot... For example, there is no [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ which would consist of eigenfunctions of $T_x$. The same applies for the free Hamiltonian. Every self-adjoint operator has a spectral measure and is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication by a real function on  $L^2(M \subset \mathbb R, \mathrm{d}\mu)$, but AFAIK doesn't have a _basis of eigenvectors_ in any common meaning of the words.

Comment: @m93a : you'll have a measure that weights the *classical* eigenfunctions (*classical* meaning the eigenfunctions are classical pointwise solutions of the eigenvalue problem, but may not be in $L^2$, even though integrals of them with respect to the eigenvalue parameter and spectral measure *are* in $L^2$.) Here's a link to another answer of mine in this regard: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649303/eigenvalue-equation-and-separable-solutions/1649477#1649477 )

Comment: Interesting! So if I understand correctly, the classical solutions to the Sturm-Liouville equation correspond to the points in the spectrum of the Sturm-Liouville operator on $L^2(\Omega \subset \mathbb R)$, and every vector in $L^2(\Omega)$ has an expansion in terms of these classical solutions, is that right? Do you have any reading recommendations where I could learn this more systematically? The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) about the S-L operator has a nice overview of this, but only for the *regular* S-L problem on a bounded interval.

Comment: @m93a : Search for Anton Zettl on Amazon. There's a classical volume that appears, and then a new one that I have not looked at, which concerns recent advances. To gain a classic understanding, look for Titchmarsh's book on eigenfunction expansions. Titchmarsh uses complex function theory to prove everything; he was a pioneer in this field.